# Change order of blocks at Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-blocks

How can I change order of blocks on the right block on [this website](http://nineteenfifteen.prototype-interactive.com/category/seasons/summer-2012) (it's Drupal)?
There are two blocks "Pick of the week" and "Archives", I'd like to put "Archives" to the top and "Pick of the week" to the bottom.

Comment: just change their order in Structures? click and drag the one u want to come first to be on top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your admin you can go to the Blocks page (admin/structure/blocks).

Find the region you want to change and then use the drag and drop to change the order the blocks appear in. Don't forget to press "save changes" at the bottom of the page.

[image]

Comment: its not so easy in my case:
my page with box looks like: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/38721261/%D0%9C%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80/blocks.png
  
and I got 404 error page on: http://domain/admin/structure/blocks

Comment: What version of  Drupal is that? It doesn't look like 6 or 7 to me.

Comment: That is odd. There should be reordering in D6. Can you access the DB?

Comment: seems to be some javascript issue with the theme, you can try to resolve that first, else update blocks weight from the db

Comment: I have done it for you for now, I logged in to your dev site with default credentials and it worked, and found there is no javascript error thrown then I saw the source of it, found you have added "/sites/all/themes/1915com/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js?C", please remove this, this is not allowing the draggable stuff to execute, contact me in skype: nikunj.kotecha, if you want more details how I did it.

Answer (score 0):

Structure > Blocks > Sidebar Second

Drag Archives and put it on top of Pick of the week.